# An Olympiad geometry question; Angle chase, Orthocenter, Bash, Circles.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Points $O$ and $H$ are the circumcenter and orthocenter of acute triangle $ABC$, respectively. The perpendicular bisector of segment $AH$ meets sides $AB$ and $AC$ at $D$ and $E$, respectively. Prove that $\angle DOA= \angle EOA$.
[image: Figure 1]

After drawing the diagram; I was stuck
so,  I figured I knew the coordinates of all points so I should coord bash this
but it was a very tedious computation and I must have made a mistake somewhere as I couldn't get the right solution. (P.S. if you want me to share my failed coordinate bash, do let me know though my handwriting is not very good).

[My work](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:eef37a59-983a-4222-bee3-d464e0bd3cc8)

A elementary solution/trigonometrical/coordinate bash would be ideal but any solution would mean a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Olympiad problem or not, you are still expected to add context other than a mere statement of the problem and expecting us to do it for you.  What work did you do when "coord bashing" that was tedious and in which you couldn't get the right solution?  Please show us that work.

Comment: @amWhy ok I am sorry, i am attaching my work

Comment: @amWhy , https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:eef37a59-983a-4222-bee3-d464e0bd3cc8 here is the pdf document, my handwriting is not very neat tho (it's understandable); i am sorry for that

Comment: @amWhy , should i also put this link on the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First see that $\triangle ADH\sim\triangle AOC$, so $\triangle ADO\sim\triangle AHC$ (either by spiral similarity, or look at length ratios).

Similarly, $\triangle AEO\sim\triangle AHB$. So $\angle DOA=\angle HCA=\angle HBA=\angle EOA$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i understood the first similarity but am not able to prove the second one. I am not very familiar with spiral similarity, could you please explain how $\Delta ADH$ ~ $\Delta AOC$ , thanks!

Comment: @Aditya_math I'm guessing you mean $\triangle ADO\sim\triangle AHC$? Once you have the first similarity proved, note that $AD/AO=AH/AC$. Together with $\angle OAD=\angle CAH$, this proves the second similarity.

Comment: yes, sorry that is what i meant. Thanks for this wonderful answer. I just have one last question, how did you figure out those two triangles would be similar?

Comment: @Aditya_math One thing that happens when you do way too many of these kind of questions in school is that facts like $\angle BAH=\angle OAC$ become as automatic as $1+1=2$.